# DML operation Delete not allowed on PermissionSet

Tags: apex, managed-package, permission-sets

I have an apex class which has the code to delete permissionSet after checking its permissionSetAssignments. It works when I run the code from anonymous window but not from uninstall handler which called at uninstalling of package from org.

The code is like below:

```
List<PermissionSet> permissionSets = [SELECT Id, Name FROM PermissionSet WHERE Name IN :permissionSetNames];

if(Schema.sObjectType.PermissionSet.isDeletable()){

    // Delete the Permission Set
    Database.delete(permissionSets);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you posted this using a different account yesterday or earlier today (I can't find it now).

In the other question you suggested the perm set was part of your package. In which case, this makes sense. See the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pkg2_dev.meta/pkg2_dev/packaging_packageable_components.htm#mdc_permission_set) where you will see that these components can be removed from the package. However, that doesn't mean you can actually delete them directly through code, since this is package metadata.

I recommend you simply have the uninstaller find and remove the related perm set assignments (these are not packaged metadata) and rely on the deinstallation of the package to deal with removing the packaged metadata including these perm sets.

NB as the note in the docs:

> When a package developer removes this component from a package, the component remains in a subscriber’s org after they install the upgraded package. The admin of the subscriber’s org can then delete the component, if desired.

So it may even be that the perm sets become unpackaged metadata in the org after the uninstall. You probably cannot do anything about that, *if* this is what happens - the note relates to a different scenario, but it **may** also impact your situation.